# Is there any method to count different items in the text file for every matched string and store in dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, string, file-io, text-files

The text file looks like

data/File_10265.data:

Apple:2kg

Apple:3kg

Banana:1kg

Banana:4kg

Some string1

data/File_10276.data:

Apple:6kg

Apple:5kg

Apple:3kg

Banana:2kg

Banana:4kg

Banana:2kg

Banana:4kg

Extra line

data/File_10278.data:

Apple:3kg

Banana:2kg

Banana:4kg

Banana:2kg

Banana:7kg

Some words

The code is as follows:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
f = open("Samplefruit.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
Apple_count=0
Banana_count=0
File_count=0
Filename_list=[]
Apple_list=[]
Banana_list=[]
for line in lines:
    match1=re.findall('data/(?P<File>[^\/]+(?=\..*data))',line)    
    if match1:
        Filename_list.append(match1[0])
        print('Match found:',match1)           
    if line.startswith("Apple"):
        Apple_count+=1
    elif line.startswith("Banana"):
        Banana_count+=1
    Apple_list.append(Apple_count)
    Banana_list.append(Banana_count)
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Filename': Filename_list,'Apple': 
    Apple_list,'Banana': 
    Banana_list})
```

The desired output:

Filename: |Apple  |Banana

File_10265|2      |2

File_10276|3      |4

File_10278|1      |4

Comment: Try construction a *counting hash* for each file (`{ "Apple"=> 2, "Banana"=>2 }`, `{ "Apple"=> 3, "Banana"=>4 }` and `{ "Apple"=> 1, "Banana"=>4 }`).  After reading each `Filename:File_XXXXX`, create an empty hash `h` (er, I guess "dictionary" in Python). Then when reading fruits (say `"Apple"`) check if `h` has a key `"Apple"`. If it does *not* set `h["Apple"] = 1`; if it does set `h["Apple"] = h["Apple"] + 1`....

Comment: ...The hash is complete when you read the next `Filename:File_XXXXX` or you reach the end of the file. One advantage of this approach is that you don't have to read the entire file into memory ("gulp" it) before performing the calculations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for your suggestion. Each fruit item has a quantity. I have to count each fruit item and add it to the list.

Comment: Ah, yes, but that's just a small change. When reading fruits, such as `"Apple:2kg"`, convert to `k = "Apple", v = 2`, then if `h` does not have a key `"Apple"`, set `h["Apple"] = k`; else `h["Apple"] = h["Apple"] + k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have posted an answer. Thanks, @Mani,@CarySwoveland, @Zero, and @M B for your support. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
text = {}
with open(r"Samplefruit.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "data" in line:
            Filename=line.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
            Apple_count=0
            Banana_count=0
            print('----------------')            
            print(Filename)                   
        elif ("Apple" in  line or "Banana" in  line):                                          
            if line.startswith("Apple"):            
                Apple_count+=1
            elif line.startswith("Banana"):
                Banana_count+=1
            print('Apple:',Apple_count)
            print('Banana:',Banana_count)
        text[Filename] = {'Apple':Apple_count,'Banana':Banana_count}
    File_list.append(Filename)
  
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Filename": text.keys(), "Apple":  [x['Apple'] for x in text.values()],"Banana":  [x['Banana'] for x in text.values()]}

    )
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this but here's one solution:

```
with open('filetest.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    unique_lines = list(dict.fromkeys(lines))
    for line in unique_lines:
        print(line + str(lines.count(line)))
        f1 = open('file.txt', 'a')
        f1.write(line + str(lines.count(line)))
        f1.close()
```

You simply open the file, read all lines into a list, then get rid of any duplicates. Then you loop through the list (now with the duplicates removed), and use the `.count` ([docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/tuple/count.html)) function to get the number of occurrences of each unique item in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this code could not show the correct output.  I am stuck with a loop to start, count the items until another Filename is found. Finally, add calculated items and Filename to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
pattern = re.compile(r"data/File_[\d]+.data:")

lines = text.split("\n")
files = itertools.groupby(lines, lambda line:pattern.search(line) == None)

for k, content in files:
  if k == True:
    content = list(content)
    all_words = list(set(content))
    counts = {word:content.count(word) for word in all_words if word != ""}
    print(counts)
```

Output -

```
{'Banana:': 2, 'Apple:': 2}
{'Banana:': 4, 'Apple:': 3}
{'Banana:': 4, 'Apple:': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: New changes have been made to the code as per the changes in the question.

Try this:

```
import re
text = {}

def unit_cal(val1, val2):    #function to add  quantities with units and return the final answer with units
    q1 = re.findall("[0-9]+", val1)
    unit = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", val1)
    if (val2 != False):
        q2  = re.findall("[0-9]+", val2)
        ans = int(q1[0]) + int(q2[0])
    else:
        ans = int(q1[0])
    return str(ans) + unit[0]   #remove + unit[0] to return only the value

with open("item.txt", "r") as f1:
    for line in f1:  
        if ("data" in  line): 
            temp_key = line
            k = {}
            text[temp_key] = k
        elif (line.strip() != ""):            
            temp_word = line.strip().split(":")
            
            if temp_word[0] in text[temp_key]:
                text[temp_key][temp_word[0]] = unit_cal(temp_word[1], text[temp_key][temp_word[0]])
            else:
                text[temp_key][temp_word[0]] = unit_cal(temp_word[1], False)
                   
final_text = ""

for main_key in text:
    final_text += main_key + "\n"
    for sub_key in text[main_key]:
        final_text += sub_key + " : " + str(text[main_key][sub_key]) + "\n\n"

print(final_text)  #final output is displayed in the idle

with open("new_items.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(final_text)    #the output is also written to a new file
```

Output:

```
data/File_10265.data:

Apple : 5kg

Banana : 5kg

data/File_10276.data:

Apple : 14kg

Banana : 12kg

data/File_10278.data:

Apple : 3kg

Banana : 15kg
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Mani, I  appreciate your attempt. But, I have each fruit item in quantities as shown in the question. I have counted as well, the problem occurred while adding counts to the list.

Comment: @zma I have made changes to the code. : )

Comment: @Mani thanks again for your extra effort. This code perfectly works to compute the quantity of fruit. This will help others with similar problems. But, I have to count only the occurrence of the fruit in each Filename. Please look at the expected output. There are some random lines in the text file in question. I have to create a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or [data frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with column Filename, Apple count, and Banana count. Your assistance is appreciated.